# Find $a$ such that family of $x^2+ay^2=r^2$ is orthogonal to $y=5x^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I got a different solution from my professor on this exercise:

> Find $a>0$ such that the family of ellipses $x^2+ay^2=r^2$ is orthogonal to $y=5x^2$, with $r>0$.
>
> Solution: $a=2$.

Let me show you what I've done:

The family of orthogonal curves to $f(x,y,r)=x^2+ay^2-r^2$ is

$$2x-2ay\cdot\frac{dx}{dy}=0 \implies \frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{1}{a}ydy \implies Kx=e^{1/{a}}\cdot{y}$$

Hence

$$y=kxe^{1/a}$$

is the family of orthogonal curves to the ellipse.

But that's nowhere close to $y=5x^2$, and of course if I do $a=2$ my solution is not equal to $y=5x^2$, given that $K$ and $a$ must be constants and cannot depend on $x$.

Therefore I came up with the solution that $y-5x^2=0$ cannot be orthogonal to $x^2+ay^2-r^2=0$.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The word you are looking for is *ellipse*, with a double-ell.

Comment: Sorry, fixed now.

Comment: You missed one. But I fixed it.

Comment: $2x-2ay\cdot\frac{dx}{dy}=0$ is incorrect.

Comment: missing $y$ in second step

Comment: @TheStudent Thanks, fixed

Comment: @mathlove why is it wrong?

Comment: @Relure now try to slove ,may you will get your answer

Comment: @TheStudent Nope, it was a mistake while writing the solution in here, but I had that y into account while solving the problem.

Comment: By the way, why the downvote guys?

Comment: i got the answer , that  $y$ ruined your whole calculation

Comment: @TheStudent Let me try again, thanks.

Comment: $2x-2ay\frac{dx}{dy}$ now $2x=2ay\frac{dx}{dy}$ which will $\frac{dy}{y}=a\frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: $\frac{d(y^2)}{dx}=\frac{d(y^2)}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivatives of the ellipse and the parabola are, respectively,

$$y_e' = -\frac x{ay}, \>\>\>\> y_p'=10x$$

Their orthogonality requires $y_w'y_p' = -1$, or

$$ 10x^2 = ay$$

Plug it into $y=5x^2$ to obtain $a = 2$. Thus, the family of $x^2+2y^2 =r^2$ is orthogonal to $y=5x^2$. Shown below is an example for $r=5$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WLOG any point on $y=5x^2$ is $P(t,5t^2)$

$$y_p=\dfrac{dy}{dx}_{x=t}=10t$$

$y_e=\dfrac{dy}{dx}_{x=t}$ for $x^2+ay^2=r^2,$

$$y_e=-\dfrac{2x}{2ay}_{x=t}=-\dfrac t{a(5t^2)}$$

If $y_e\cdot y_p=-1,$ $$-1=-\dfrac t{a(5t^2)}\cdot10t=-\dfrac 2a$$

As $P$ resides on the eclipse, $$r^2=t^2+a(5t^2)^2,r>0\implies t\ne0$$

Comment: @Isham, Thanks for the observation.